# Jenkins Active Choices Reactive Reference Parameter does not work with Formatted HTML Input-Text-Box

Tags: html, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I've created a Jenkins job that uses the Active Choice Reactive Reference Parameter plugin. For one of my parameters I would like for users to be able to freely input a number value. I managed to get the input box to display correctly within the Build page, however, the specified value is not being passed along as a variable for that specific parameter name.

Here is my Groovy Script: Option_F (parameter name)

```
if (Option_A.equals("Load_Test")) {
 return "<input name='Calls Per Second' type='text' placeholder='Calls Per Second'>"
} else if (Option_A.equals("Functional_Test")) {
 return "<input name='Not_Applicable' type='text' placeholder='Not_Applicable' 
value='Not_Applicable'>"
}
```

This is the outcome: https://www.screencast.com/t/ZTWwVI3d0sSw

^^^ Numerical values inserted into the input-text-box (along with other Parameters in the job) are passed along and established as [variables](https://www.screencast.com/t/2tMNW4SkghR). I then pass these variables as Python arguments using a shell script. The other Parameter variables work as intended but this one still appears as a blank value within the [console output](https://www.screencast.com/t/mCxDCYM0).

I've also attempted to follow the recommended steps  within the [plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) (Passing Reactive Reference Values to the build) but that seemed to make the Parameter entirely inoperable.

Recommended Groovy Script:

```
if (Option_A.equals("Load_Test")) {
 return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"${ReactiveRefParam}\" class=\"setting- 
input\" type=\"text\">"
} else if (Option_A.equals("Functional_Test")) {
return "<input name=\"value\" value=\"${ReactiveRefParam}\" class=\"setting- 
input\" type=\"text\">"
}
```

Recommendation Outcome: https://www.screencast.com/t/HNkQ7aa7Y2

I know that I could easily swap this out for a String Parameter (which I have done as a temporary solution) but I'd like to get this working if possible.

Comment: Have you tried it with the spaces ?? `Calls Per Second` to `Calls_Per_Second`

Answer (score 2):

After trying so many ways I came up with a way to use the variable in execute shell or some other place . I saw the solution somewhere and gave it a try and it worked .

You can use the variable by using `${value}`.

In your case may be you can try `${Option_F}`.

Hope it helps.